# Firebase cloud functions deploy errorTS2614

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, geofirestore

I am getting the below error while deploying firebase cloud functions. This is happening after upgrading firebase-tool and npm to the latest versions.

```
node_modules/geofirestore/dist/GeoFirestoreTypes.ts:3:10 - error TS2614: 

Module
'"**/flutter/project123/functions/node_modules/geofirestore/node_modules/firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'.

Did you mean to use 'import firestore from
 "**/flutter/project123/functions/node_modules/geofirestore/node_modules/firebase"' instead?

3 import { firestore as webfirestore } from 'firebase/app';
```

Package.json

```
    {
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^3.7.3",
    "firebase": "^7.13.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.11.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.15.4",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.3.0",
    "geofirestore": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: the imports i am using are as below "import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as geofire from 'geofirestore';"

Comment: Try adding `import 'firebase/firestore';` ...this is what it complains about, because `firebase/app` does not have it (anymore).

Comment: sorry. its not working, get the same error

Comment: Without the `package.json` and the TS/JS which produces the error, this question is quite theoretical; please don't add code into comments, but [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68920169/edit) the question. In case you've recently upgrade to GeoFirestore v4, there's even an upgrade script: https://gist.github.com/MichaelSolati/874543594145fa29691b883835a73460

Comment: hi, Please see package.json file. There was no issue with the script files. getting error only after upgrading firebase-tools and npm to latest versions

Comment: upgrading of firebase-tools, npm and firebase-functions to latest versions is causing this issue. Rolled back firebase-tools to 8.20.0, npm to 6.14.13 and firebase-functions to 3.14.1

Comment: Just update your imports to match the new version ...

Comment: Can you please let me know or tell me where to find the proper imports. Firebase-functions 3.15.4, firebase-tools 9.3 and npm 7.21. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The imports for [`geofirestore`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geofirestore) should generically look alike this (much has changed with v8):

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import * as geofirestore from 'geofirestore';
```

This import only works with v7 (and should be substituted with the above):

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
```

Comment: ok. have updated the question with the imports i am using.